# How to say naturally when you look at your child's face and have a feeling that he has done things suspiciously?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

You look at your son's face and he smiles at you in a suspicious way. That makes you have a feeling that he has done things suspiciously like sneaking sugar in the kitchen.

**How to say naturally in the situation?**

For example,

-*You look suspicious*

-*You look sneaky*

-*You look dodgy*

-*You look guilty*

-*What have you been up to?*

-*I can tell from your face that you have done something sneaky.*

etc

Comment: If I ever have a son, he can sneak sugar *into* my kitchen anytime!

Comment: He didn't do those things suspiciously. He may be acting that way now.

Comment: @Micah, this kid has a lot to put up with.